# Why pass input/output stream in a function?

Tags: c++, stream

Why would we want to do this:

```
#include <iostream>

void print(std::ostream& os) {
  os << "Hi";
}

int main() {
  print(std::cout);
  return 0;
}
```

instead of this:

```
#include <iostream>

void print() {
  std::cout << "Hi";
}

int main() {
  print();
  return 0;
}
```

Is there some certain advantage or functionality that is obtained only with the first version?

Comment: The first version you can print to any `ostream` (`cout`, files, string streams, whatever). The second version only works with `cout`.

Comment: I presume that you know that _any_ `std::ostream` can be passed to the first version, and not just `std::cout`?

Comment: Well, what if you wan to print the text to someplace other than `cout`?  Like to a file for instance.

Comment: I guess I don't know many ostreams...

Comment: Even if there were not already _"many ostreams"_, like [`std::fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) or [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) or [`std::spanstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_spanstream), someone anywhere could create a class that derives from `std::ostream` and use it with the first version of your function.  But not the second.

Comment: It's similar to how `void greet(std::string x) { cout << "Hello, " << x; }` is more generally useful than `void greet() { cout << "Hello, ilsec"; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the first version is significantly better. Like already mentioned in the comments, it allows you to use any kind of `std::ostream`, not just `std::cout`. Some of the most important consequences of this architectural choice are:

1. You can use your function to print the required data to standard output, a file, a custom class written by your colleagues (e.g. database adapter, logger).
2. It is possible to test your `void print` function. E.g.:

```
TEST(MyFunctionShould, printHello)
{
  std::string expectedResult("Hello");
  std::ostringstream oss;
  print(oss);
  ASSERT_EQ(expectedResult, oss.str());
}
```